# Connecting to Cassandra with PySpark, getting "StackOverFlowError"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm working with a cassandra table with about 30 million data, so my partitions are quite large.I just want decrease my read data time , according to this goal i am trying use spark with cassandra. When I connect from spark to cassandra and try to show() the data  I get a stack overflow error. But when i am read the same data from csv there is no problem with manipulate data. Because of that i think that there is no problem with the size of the data. But I don't understand what the real problem is.

with the following codes i am connecting cassandra from spark and read cassandra table.

```
bin/pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0
```

```py
hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'node1_ip,node2_ip,node3_ip',
   "table":"ex_table","keyspace":"ex_keyspace"}
data_frame=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .options(**hosts).load()
```

after that when i trying to run data_frame.show() i am getting error like below.

```
">  >>> hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'10.0.0.10,10.0.0.11,10.0.0.12',"table":"dummy_table","keyspace":"dummy_keyspace"}
> >>> data_frame=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**hosts).load()
> >>> data_frame.show() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "{<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
> "/home/pc3/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 494, in show
>     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))   File "/home/pc3/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> line 1321, in __call__   File
> "/home/pc3/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
>     return f(*a, **kw)   File "/home/pc3/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> line 326, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o52.showString. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1190)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
>   at}
```

...
...
...

Not : when that code working my ram is not filling too much but one of my core values ​​are getting to 80% 90% (I have total 20 core).
Hardware: I have 3 node (rf:3) each of that have 20 core , each of that have 1tb ssd , each of that have 64gb ram.

**Edit:**
When i use this command on linux terminal like that ./bin/pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss16m it worked.

Comment: You need to post longer stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sir , but i'm not sure what do you mean , what is longer stacktrace ? How can i post longer stacktrace ?

Comment: or it's only the log that you got?

Comment: A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I updated post now can you check again ?